# Opencv Algorithm to detect moving vehicle in moving/shaking camera

Tags: opencv, object-detection, motion-detection

Is there any way in `opencv` to detect moving `vehicle/object` when camera is `moving/shaking`.

I have read and implemented various Object Detection algorithms in `opencv`, but also they detect `false areas` of frame because of shaking camera.

If you have any solution please help.

Thanks.

Comment: there's a videostab module for this.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have two issues to be solved,

1. Detection
2. Stabilization

For detection, you have few methods, but if you have various different shapes to be detected if prefer that you try the cascade classifiers., Here you can detect what you want, but you need to do training phase for your objectives (positive and negative images.). it is so simple to train you obejects. [Here](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Vehicle-Detection-Tracking-and-Counting/4057777) you find a detailed project, same as yours. 
[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) opencv explains you how to train your images to get a classifiers.

For stabilization, I suggest you to see the algorithm of tracking.[This project](http://code.google.com/p/opencv-lane-vehicle-track/) implements a basic realtime lane and vehicle tracking using OpenCV. . If I were you i calculate the optical flow for each pair and track them by the similarity between them.
Ma be you need to see in Opencv:

1. [optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html)
2. [compute the similarity between images](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html)
3. if you need to stabilize the shaking images you have to mix the two previous steps.

Let'us know once you need more explainantion

Comment: dervish, I tried using optical flow as you suggested, As you know camera is moving and car is also moving. I have drawn flow vectors. Now the issue is that I don't know how to differentiate between the flow vectors of moving car and shaking camera.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOaKnCSejXQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BGSLibrary that andrew and some other contributors wrote on [GitHub](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary)  Go and try some combinations on any video that you want to process. You can develop your algorithms and easily add to the library as well.